# How to connect to the ArcGIS Server through a firewall?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, connection

I know there were a lot of similar questions, but still can't find a correct description about that. What should be inbound and outbound rules on the server side? Which ports should I use? Will that be a local or a remote port in the rule's options? Is that important (or can I) rewrite the service.txt to not to be INCREMENT and to be FEATURE? Please write me a correct answer step-by-step.

I don't understand, because you can see some of the drawings, for example:
[hardcoding port number in Arcgis License Manager](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15385/hardcoding-port-number-in-arcgis-license-manager)

says the License Server Manager is with the ArcGIS Server, not with the ArcGIS Desktop. But I can't install the License Manager to be with the ArcGIS Server. So what am I doing wrong? On my PC there's the ArcGIS Desktop and the License Server Manager. The ArcGIS Server is on an other computer. I can connect to that without the server's firewall, but that should be active...

Comment: What version of ArcGIS Server?  In 10.1 all you have to do is install the Web Adapter and open port 80.  The server does all the rest.

Comment: This question is not understandable in present form.  Arcgis server is completely separate from license server.  If you need to connect desktop to arcgis server for publishing services. Please start here and then edit you question.    http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Publishing_a_map_service/00sq00000089000000/

Answer (score 3):

I think you're confused because the linked thread makes no mention of ArcGIS Server.  When they mention "Server" they mean the server onto which the licence manager has been installed - this could be any server (but preferably it's a resilient one because if it goes down then it takes down all your GIS users with it).

Without knowing your network architecture, it's difficult to tell you how to configure your firewalls (you may have several between your desktop clients and your licence server).  Assuming your `services.txt` file looks like this:

```
SERVER this_host ANY 27000
VENDOR ARCGIS PORT=1234
FEATURE ACT ARCGIS 1 permanent 1 7ED49106D630
```

Then you should ask your network guy to set up the necessary firewall rules to allow traffic:

```
from ARCGIS_DESKTOP_CLIENT_MACHINES to LICENCE_MANAGER_SERVER on port 27000
from LICENCE_MANAGER_SERVER to ARCGIS_DESKTOP_CLIENT_MACHINES on port 1234
```